# Syntax to pass Json to rest api

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

What would be the correct syntax to pass jsondata in the following code-

I am creating a login page which would read email, password entries entered by user and upon button click json data should be passed to rest api

```
        var myemail = email.Text;
        var mypwd = password.Text;
        string jsonData = @"{""email"" : myemail, ""password"" : mypwd}"; ///SYNTAX ERROR HERE
        var content = new StringContent(jsonData,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

        var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, content);

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        await DisplayAlert(null, json, "Ok");
```

Comment: var content = new StringContent(jsonData,Encoding.UTF8,application/json"); You migth have forgot a quote here, "application/json"

Comment: I have an error at "jsonData". my actual entry fields are not being passed

Comment: `Syntax error` means the code is wrong and has nothing to do with JSON or REST. The code you posted *won't* throw any errors. It contains hard-coded values, not any emails or passwords. What is the actual code and the *actual* compiler error?

Comment: In any case, you can't pass text data in JSON without quoting it which means the eamil and password *values* need quotes. If you use raw input any input that contains double quotes will result in an invalid string and possibly expose your application to hacking. The *easy* way to escape the input is to use a proper JSON serializer instead of constructing the string yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write your own JSON strings, especially not when they contain user input, because what if a password contains a `"` or `\`?

Create an anonymous object, and let a serialization library handle that:

```
var jsonObject = new {
    email = email.Text,
    password = password.Text,
};  

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);

var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```